# What is the type for |x| move |y| x + y?

Tags: rust

What is the type for

```
let plus:Plus = |x| move |y| x + y;
```

Obviously,

```
type Plus = fn(isize) -> fn(isize) -> isize;
```

won't work since the last part is not a function pointer but a closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type is `impl Fn(isize) -> (impl Fn(isize) -> isize)`. It can be coerced to `fn(isize) -> (impl Fn(isize) -> isize)`, because the outer closure does not capture.

However, you cannot express this type in today's Rust. With the nightly feature `type_alias_impl_trait`, you can break it into two types:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type Adder = impl Fn(isize) -> isize;
type Plus = fn(isize) -> Adder;
let plus: Plus = |x| move |y| x + y;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d493200331951e8a4e39e492aa54144c).

Or you can box it:

```rust
type Plus = fn(isize) -> Box<dyn Fn(isize) -> isize>;
let plus: Plus = |x| Box::new(move |y| x + y);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=211fca8be00709548282ed5cf1b8b146).

Comment: Thanks a lot Chayim. I try to install the nightly. I prefer the first syntax, but do you think the `feature(type_alias_impl_trait)` will become stable shortly or still takes a time?

Comment: Also, I'd like to know how this solution is generic approach other than `isize`. If we still needs to be boxed for any other complicated type in any way, I must re-consider,so. Thanks.

Comment: @Functor It is hard to predict. However, this feature is required for async fn in traits, which has a lot of motivation to implement & stabilize as quickly as possible (lot of people are working on this). So it'll probably be stabilized soon, at least partially (although this is not necessary: generators are required for async/await yet it was stabilized years ago and they are still unstable). Take a look at [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063).

Comment: @Functor It can be generic with functions (closures cannot be generic): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=086b9812869e3d4c4c0da98c09fe0ac6

Comment: @Functor https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=532b86709812e91d3ed859b22ed7e963

Comment: Great elaboration. Thanks again! The feature implementation progress does not look look bad as you mentioned.

Comment: How about the referenced types? such as `let m = &mut x;` ?? Does this method works in a similar manner?

Comment: @Functor What do you mean?

Comment: I tried the further, but my code is messy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216280/type-for-f-move-a-a-mapf-in-rust