# Type for `|f| move |A| A.map(f)`

Tags: rust

My previous QA

[What is the type for |x| move |y| x + y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214830/what-is-the-type-for-x-move-y-x-y/71214976?noredirect=1#comment125881442_71214976)

Thanks to the provided answer, the following code works.

```
  #![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

  type Adder = impl Fn(isize) -> isize;
  type Plus = fn(isize) -> Adder;
  let plus: Plus = |x| move |y| x + y;
  println!("{}", plus(9)(1)); //10
```

Based on this, now I try to re-define map Functor.

```
  #![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

  type Mapper<A, B> = impl Fn(Vec<A>) -> Vec<B>;
  type Map = <A, B>(fn(fn(A) -> B) -> Mapper<A, B>);

  let map:Map = |f| move |A| A.map(f);

  let f = |a| a * 2;
  let A = vec![1, 2, 3];
  let B = map(f)(A);
```

However, the first line got an error: `could not find defining uses`, the second line, for `<A, B>` syntax error.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: `type Map = <A, B>(...)` should be `type Map<A, B> = ...`.

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors. Start by learning traits and generics. [The Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) is an excellent learning material. Trying to learn Rust via functional concepts is a very bad idea.

Comment: Even though it integrates some functional concepts, _Rust is not a functional language._ Trying to force pure functional concepts is doomed to frustration at best when the solution feels clunky and contrived, and failure at worst when the concept simply cannot be mapped to Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a generic function, so define one directly:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

fn main() {
    type Mapper<A, B> = impl Fn(Vec<A>) -> Vec<B>;

    //type Map<A, B> = fn(fn(A) -> B) -> Mapper<A, B>;
    //let map: Map::<A, B> = |f| move |a: Vec<A>| a.into_iter().map(f).collect();
    fn map2<A, B>(f: fn(A) -> B) -> Mapper<A, B> {
        move |a| a.into_iter().map(f).collect()
    }

    let f = |a| a * 2;
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    //let b = map(f)(a);
    let b = map2(f)(a);

    // show result
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

[Check this.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=34e4ea46b05a399814428b30ff6e756f)

Comment: Thank you rustyhu, so `map` not `map2` never works in any way?

Comment: Well, I think so. Advise you to refer to [Possible to define generic closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814423/possible-to-define-generic-closure)

Comment: Thanks. I've read the Q&A before, but will study again.